# Перевод получше для "заблокирована успокоиться"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, блокировка

Есть немного нелогичная фраза ([Tx:2148](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40263852?key=a62c4786ceb61cb9cc1b7766b2c1e5d4), [Tx:6074](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40540310?key=229e40df2284bc1723ab27d08cd748eb)):

> This account is $linkStart$temporarily suspended$linkEnd$$reason$. The suspension period ends $penaltyEndDate$.
>
> Учётная запись $linkStart$временно заблокирована,$linkEnd$$reason$. Блокировка заканчивается $penaltyEndDate$.

> to cool down
>
> чтобы успокоиться

Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обозначает она примерно вот что:

> Участник буянил, вандализировал вопросы и нехорошо ругался. Учетная запись заблокирована, чтобы он успокоился и подумал о своём поведении.

Как бы её хорошо и ёмко сформулировать?

Comment: [лемур.jpg](https://www.google.by/search?q=%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=939&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)

Answer (score 2):

<s>Пока что поправил, чтобы было более-менее гладко:</s>

Обновил согласно предложению Abyx.

> Учётная запись временно заблокирована, чтобы *позволить участнику* успокоиться. Блокировка заканчивается через 20 часов.

Comment: "чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться", а то не понятно кому надо успокоиться

Comment: @Abyx: принял вашу правку, залил в Transifex.

Answer (score 2):

> Учётная запись заблокирована на 20 часов, чтобы участник успокоился.

Comment: первый вариант нравится мне.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, но в первый нельзя подставить "вы". Или это и не требуется? А так да, первый лучше.

Comment: предлагаю разбить на два варианта. А еще я там оригинальные строки выложил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, готово. Но вообще, стоит всё-таки сообщить, какая из форм нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Участник нарушил нормы корректного поведения на сайте. Учётная запись заблокирована на 20 часов.

Comment: есть правила и нет эмоций

Comment: Бан может быть по разным причинам, не только из-за некорректного поведения. Спам, дичайший оффтопик, оскорбления, кукловодство, плагиат наверное даже.

Comment: мне кажется, Вы раскрываете именно смысл понятия "нормы корректного поведения на сайте"

Comment: Вообще, хороший вариант. Но тут есть ещё ограничение шаблона — посмотрите на обновление ответа. Получится уложить в шаблон?

Comment: Сократите на своё усмотрение, я ведь только идею выразил

Comment: Можно убрать участника, тогда получится "Нарушены нормы корректного поведения на сайте. Учётная заблокирована на 20 часов." И ничего личного. Жаль что нельзя просто: "Бан на 20 часов."

Answer (score 1):

> Учётная запись заблокирована на 20 часов, поскольку вам необходимо успокоиться.