# Локализация причин блокировки участника

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, блокировка

Одна из самых популярных (насколько я видел) причин блокировки, это дать участнику успокоиться. Как это выглядит, можно посмотреть в связанном [вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4173/176217). Но для полноты картины продублирую тут:

1. > [image: забанен без причины]
2. > [image: чтоб успокоился]
3. > [image: мета-активность]
4. > [image: основная-активность]

Видно, что имеется проблема с запятой. В одном случае она лишняя (1), в другом (4) - её не хватает. В остальных двух (2,3) - вроде бы нормально.

Корень проблемы кроется в переводе фразы [to cool down](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263852?key=a62c4786ceb61cb9cc1b7766b2c1e5d4):

> чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться

Насколько я понимаю, это единственная из причин блокировки, которая требует запятой при склеивании строк.

Поэтому предлагаю подумать над иным переводом, чтобы запятая в следующей фразе не требовалась:

> Учётная запись временно заблокирована **{тут новый перевод}**.

Попытка перенести запятую в причину ([как я думал ранее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4464/176217)), т.е. сделать так:

> , чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться

не решит проблему, т.к. при склеивании строк система ещё добавляет пробел и итоговая фраза будут выглядеть паршиво (пробелы вокруг запятой):

> Учётная запись временно заблокирована , чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться.

Как вариант, конечно, можно запросить убрать добавление пробела средствами движка, но, скорее всего, это может сильно затянуть процесс решения. Проще всего найти более подходящий перевод.

Исходное обсуждение перевода [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1850/176217).

Comment: Т.е. запятую надо убрать, а "*чтобы*" можно заменить словами "*с целью*". Imho это решает проблему

Comment: @avp или так: *"для успокоения участника"* :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевёл *"to cool down"* как:

> с целью дать участнику успокоиться

и поправил пару шаблонных строк. Теперь будет так:

> Учётная запись временно заблокирована$reason$. Срок действия блокировки истечёт $penaltyEndDate$.

> Учётная запись $linkStart$временно заблокирована$linkEnd$$reason$. Срок действия блокировки истечёт $penaltyEndDate$.

Ждём обновления транзифекса и пересборки сайта.

Строки будут полноценно применены [только на новые блокировки](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6110212#6110212), для текущих заблокированных участников текст причины блокировки останется таким, какой он был на момент блокировки. А сообщение в целом будет выглядеть несколько криво. Пример:

> [image: старая блокировка]

Т.е. часть "чтобы позволить участнику успокоиться" осталась прежней, хотя её уже нет в transifex.